# What do you call someone who reviews, and approves or denies, an application?

Tags: single-word-requests

The person who applies is called the *applicant*. What is the correct term to use for the one on the other side of an application? [such as a job application]

In my case, the *applicant* applies to be promoted as say, a super user. I want to know what is the correct way to name the one who approves or denies the application.

Comment: As the widely-varying answers indicate, we need more information about your context to answer this question with any hope of correctness. You added a parenthetical "such as a job application": is this the actual context where you need this term? If not, what is it?

Answer (score 3):

In workflow software applications, this role is commonly called the **approver**.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the type of application it is, you could use *reviewer*, or *approval official*.  In a work setting, you might use the individual's official job title instead: *hiring manager*, e.g.

Answer (score 1):

In most job-application settings, the person "on the other side of an application" is a *clerk, secretary, office worker, interviewer, owner,* or *employer*.  Particularly in small companies, the person who hands an applicant a form, tells them which boxes to complete, reads the form over,  interviews the applicant, and accepts them or not, is one and the same, the company owner.

Answer (score 0):

We call that person the application **processor**.

[Undergraduate Admissions Application Processor](http://www.ugrad.vcu.edu/apply/processor.html) at Virginia Commonwealth University.

[Membership Application Processor](http://psecu.iapplicants.com/ViewJob-380227.html) at a financial institution.